# How to know on whether my motherboard has pwm circuitry or not?

Tags: motherboard, fan

My motherboard = Hewlett-Packard 183E (U3E1). How to know on whether this has pwm (pulse width modulation) ciruitry or not?

Till now, in the forums, 4 pinned fans are said to have pwm circuitry (is it?), which I do have, but am not able to control my fans with any software using pwm.

Comment: Having PWM and being able to control it are two different things. Best source for that information is your motherboard manual.

Comment: Can certain motherboard having PWM be not controllable? 
I have laptop, it didn't come with any motherboard manual. I will search in the internet.

Comment: The BIOS would have to expose an interface/SMBus would have to be available. Most probably do this but there is no requirement to do so, from what I know. For the number of pins see also [Computer fan control - Fan Connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_fan_control#Fan_connectors).

Comment: My BIOS has only one option for fan, i.e. *Fan Always On <Enabled>*, I can only disable it. I have 4 pinned fan. I will now check on whether there is SMBus. I don't knowing anything technical, I will try. Thank you.

Comment: An example application that could help you would be [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) if it's not able  to pickup the fan you probably can't directly control it.

Comment: I have tried on being before there in windows (now I am in Zorin OS). It doesn't support my motherboard.

Comment: Here is another question in askubuntu which I have created: https://askubuntu.com/questions/952156/how-to-control-fan-speed-in-ubuntu-running-hp-laptop

Comment: From the terminal commands, I have got this: *Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, it has been reported to cause trouble on some systems. Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): YES Using driver 'i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel Panther Point (PCH) Module i2c-i801 loaded successfully.* Does that mean on my motherboard to be having SMBus?

Comment: That would be my assumption but it doesn't guarantee that you can control it. If you tried multiple tools and none of those are able to pick it up and the fan header and fan itself support PWM, I'd assume you will not be able to control it.